# I want an idea for filtering option in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create filtering system. There will be 3 filtering option.One is type of property(includes home,apartment,hostel,shop), number of room and price range. My filtering page looks like this.
[image: filtering page]

The code for filtering option component is

```
class FilterSpace extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { city: '' }
    }
    render(){

        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <p>Property Type</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <label className = "checkbox-inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="appartment" value="option1" /> Appartment
                        </label>
                        <label className = "checkbox-inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="house" value="option2" /> House
                        </label><label className = "checkbox-inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="shop" value="option1" /> Shop
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <p>Number of Rooms</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <select className = "form-control" defaultValue="Rooms">
                            <option>1 room</option>
                            <option>2 rooms</option>
                            <option>3 rooms</option>
                            <option>4 rooms</option>
                            <option>5+ rooms</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-3">
                        <p>Price Range</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <input type="range" min="1000" max="30000" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
    }
}
export default FilterSpace;
```

Whenever user selects for property type to lets say home then all the result that has property type home should be listed below. For this do i need onChange event on every input button and select button ? What else should i have to do? I just need an idea.

My API looks like this

```
"objects": [
    {
      "amenities": "Kitchen, Cable, Attached Bathroom, Internet",
      "city": "Biratnagar",
      "created_on": "2016-04-25T05:54:48.542759",
      "email": "example@gmail.com",
      "gallery": [
        {
          "id": 10,
          "image": "/media/upload/hostel2.jpg",
          "rental": "/api/v1/rental/32/",
          "resource_uri": "/api/v1/gallery/10/"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "image": "/media/upload/hostel1.jpg",
          "rental": "/api/v1/rental/32/",
          "resource_uri": "/api/v1/gallery/11/"
        }
      ],
      "id": 32,
      "is_published": true,
      "listingName": "ganesh chowk hostel",
      "modified_on": "2016-04-25T05:54:48.542816",
      "ownerName": "name of rent owner",
      "phoneNumber": 9842333833,
      "place": "Ganesh Chowk",
      "price": 6000,
      "property": "hostel",
      "resource_uri": "/api/v1/rental/32/",
      "room": 3,
      "slug": "ganesh-chowk-hostel",
      "summary": "We offer you comfortable room with educational environment to you. Inverter is provided for one bulb on each room. The price is reasonable with charge of 2000 per room. For more detail contact us on our phone number provided.",
      "water": "yes"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you post API doc link or how you are calling the API?

Comment: http://commonrentspace.me/api/v1/rental/?format=json i will be fetching this api using axios

Answer (score 1):

On each input, you should link the event onChange with a function of the component (`handleInputOnChange(event) {}`) and there, make a call to your API.

Remember, to bind the function with the component context.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { city: '' }

    this.handleInputOnChange = this.handleInputOnChange.bind(this);
}

handleInputOnChange(event) {
    //Handle event
}

render() {
    return(
        ...
        <input onChange={ this.handleInputOnChange } />
        ...
    );
}
```

I hope it works for you ;)

Comment: Do i need to use filtering option's type in this.state = { house:' ',apartment:' ',shop:' ',rooms:[] }?

Comment: I cannot say. It depends how you make the API calls, how you want to structure the request from the state, how do you process the request....